# Shipstation imports both Configurable and Associated Products for just one item

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

So we work with Shipstation for processing orders and somehow, Magento keeps pushing both the configurable item and the associated item inside said configurable to Shipstation, doubling the item count... My "Import Child Products" option has already been set to "No". Any idea as to what could cause this? Thanks!

Comment: what version of Magento are you on?

Comment: Magento ver. 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Did you try reaching out to ShipStation? Unless you changed something on the Magento side of things this would be an issue with ShipStation.

You stated in your Question that

> Magento keeps pushing both the configurable ...

I would suggest that you check with SHipStation because the way their integartion work is that they **pull** data from Magento - Magento doesn't push anything to them.

Comment: thank you very much! i'll try to reach out to them

Comment: The thing is the orders from ebay and amazon that are processed to magento and then pulled by shipstation are just fine... So is this anything?

Comment: Those orders have configurable items?

Comment: Yes. And I think that the two items showing up are the configurable listing and the child listing

Comment: Here's what the Shipstation Cust Rep said: "So, for some reason, Magento is actually telling ShipStation that order has 2 items, even though that should only be one thing ( a parent SKU) however Magento is telling ShipStation those are actually two separate items, and so ShipStation is displaying that info."